# Fancybox - Calling a fancybox modal dialog inside a fancybox callback

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using Fancybox to show a form.

In that form, when it is submitted, the code processes the form stuff via Ajax.

After it is done, I want the code to show a modal dialog informing the user of an action like "action done!"

I have this JS code here

```
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterShow: function() {
        $( '#foo_form' ).on( 'submit', function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: $( this ).attr('action'),
                data: $( this ).serializeArray(),
                type: 'POST'
            }).done(function() {
                $.fancybox.close();

                // TODO: Possible to call Modal Fancybox dialog here?
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Is it possible to call modal fancybox dialog?

Answer (score 0):

You may have two options :

1). Inside the `.done()` method, instead of using `$.fancybox.close();` use `$.fancybox.open("action done!");` ... that will close the existing fancybox and open the new message you want in fancybox.

2). Add an `afterClose` callback to your existing code and call the new fancybox message using the `$.fancybox.open("action done!");` method.

I would use the first option though.

**Notice** that in any case, you can only have **ONE** fancybox opened at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the first option because, like you, it is the better one. But I get this message `The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later.`. Any ideas why?

Comment: The call is inside an `afterShow` fancybox callback. It might caused some problems.